# XSLT Transformation : for each

Tags: xslt

Below is the xml input to xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Header><LimitInfoHeader><limitInfo><current>4930</current><limit>5000000</limit><type>API REQUESTS</type></limitInfo></LimitInfoHeader></soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <queryResponse>
            <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
                <done>true</done>
                <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                    <sf:type>Account</sf:type>
                    <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <sf:Contacts xsi:type="QueryResult">
                        <done>true</done>
                        <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                            <sf:type>Contact</sf:type>
                            <sf:Id>0031700000ThqzkAAB</sf:Id>
                            <sf:Id>0031700000ThqzkAAB</sf:Id>
                        </records>
                        <size>1</size>
                    </sf:Contacts>
                    <sf:Opportunities xsi:type="QueryResult">
                        <done>true</done>
                        <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                            <sf:type>Opportunity</sf:type>
                            <sf:Id>0061700000BB1kRAAT</sf:Id>
                            <sf:Id>0061700000BB1kRAAT</sf:Id>
                        </records>
                        <size>1</size>
                    </sf:Opportunities>
                </records>
                ***<records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                    <sf:type>Account</sf:type>
                    <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <sf:Contacts xsi:type="QueryResult">
                        <done>true</done>
                        <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                            <sf:type>Contact</sf:type>
                            <sf:Id>0031a00000Kdu8zAAB</sf:Id>
                            <sf:Id>0031a00000Kdu8zAAB</sf:Id>
                        </records>
                        <size>1</size>
                    </sf:Contacts>
                    <sf:Opportunities xsi:type="QueryResult">
                        <done>true</done>
                        <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                            <sf:type>Opportunity</sf:type>
                            <sf:Id>0061a00000Ej6JwAAJ</sf:Id>
                            <sf:Id>0061a00000Ej6JwAAJ</sf:Id>
                        </records>
                        <size>1</size>
                    </sf:Opportunities>
                </records>
                <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                    <sf:type>Account</sf:type>
                    <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <sf:Contacts xsi:type="QueryResult">
                        <done>true</done>
                        <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                            <sf:type>Contact</sf:type>
                            <sf:Id>0031a00000HcNSDAA3</sf:Id>
                            <sf:Id>0031a00000HcNSDAA3</sf:Id>
                        </records>
                        <size>1</size>
                    </sf:Contacts>
                    <sf:Opportunities xsi:type="QueryResult">
                        <done>true</done>
                        <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                            <sf:type>Opportunity</sf:type>
                            <sf:Id>0061a00000Ej6JDAAZ</sf:Id>
                            <sf:Id>0061a00000Ej6JDAAZ</sf:Id>
                        </records>
                        <size>1</size>
                    </sf:Opportunities>
                </records>***
                <size>3</size>
            </result>
        </queryResponse>
    </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

below is the xslt code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"
    xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com"
    xmlns:sfdc="sfdc">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <sfdc:sObjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc" type="OpportunityContactRole">
            <xsl:for-each select="//ns:queryResponse/ns:result/ns:records">
                <xsl:if test="//ns:records/sf:Contacts/ns:done/text() = 'true' and //ns:records/sf:Opportunities/ns:done/text() = 'true'"> 
                <sfdc:sObject>
                    <sfdc:ContactId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//ns:records/sf:Contacts/ns:records/sf:Id[1]/text()"/>
                    </sfdc:ContactId>
                    <sfdc:IsPrimary>True</sfdc:IsPrimary>
                    <OpportunityId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//ns:records/sf:Opportunities/ns:records/sf:Id[1]/text()"/>
                    </OpportunityId>
                    <sfdc:Role>Purchaser</sfdc:Role>
                </sfdc:sObject>
               </xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </sfdc:sObjects>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

below is the output which i got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sfdc:sObjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc" xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"
    xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" type="OpportunityContactRole">
    <sfdc:sObject>
        <sfdc:ContactId>0031700000ThqzkAAB</sfdc:ContactId>
        <sfdc:IsPrimary>True</sfdc:IsPrimary>
        <OpportunityId>0061700000BB1kRAAT</OpportunityId>
        <sfdc:Role>Purchaser</sfdc:Role>
    </sfdc:sObject>
    <sfdc:sObject>
        <sfdc:ContactId>0031700000ThqzkAAB</sfdc:ContactId>
        <sfdc:IsPrimary>True</sfdc:IsPrimary>
        <OpportunityId>0061700000BB1kRAAT</OpportunityId>
        <sfdc:Role>Purchaser</sfdc:Role>
    </sfdc:sObject>
    <sfdc:sObject>
        <sfdc:ContactId>0031700000ThqzkAAB</sfdc:ContactId>
        <sfdc:IsPrimary>True</sfdc:IsPrimary>
        <OpportunityId>0061700000BB1kRAAT</OpportunityId>
        <sfdc:Role>Purchaser</sfdc:Role>
    </sfdc:sObject>
</sfdc:sObjects>
```

here in the above generated output, the iteration is happening sucessfully, but only the first records values are considered
i.e 0031700000ThqzkAAB and 0061700000BB1kRAAT

why the second and third record values (highlighted in the input xml) does exists in the output.? not able to understand.

in summary below is the desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sfdc:sObjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc" xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"
    xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" type="OpportunityContactRole">
    <sfdc:sObject>
        <sfdc:ContactId>0031700000ThqzkAAB</sfdc:ContactId>
        <sfdc:IsPrimary>True</sfdc:IsPrimary>
        <OpportunityId>0061700000BB1kRAAT</OpportunityId>
        <sfdc:Role>Purchaser</sfdc:Role>
    </sfdc:sObject>
    <sfdc:sObject>
        <sfdc:ContactId>0031a00000Kdu8zAAB</sfdc:ContactId>
        <sfdc:IsPrimary>True</sfdc:IsPrimary>
        <OpportunityId>0061a00000Ej6JwAAJ</OpportunityId>
        <sfdc:Role>Purchaser</sfdc:Role>
    </sfdc:sObject>
    <sfdc:sObject>
        <sfdc:ContactId>0031a00000HcNSDAA3</sfdc:ContactId>
        <sfdc:IsPrimary>True</sfdc:IsPrimary>
        <OpportunityId>0061a00000Ej6JDAAZ</OpportunityId>
        <sfdc:Role>Purchaser</sfdc:Role>
    </sfdc:sObject>
</sfdc:sObjects>
```

requesting to please help me output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inside of your `xsl:for-each`, the context is `//ns:queryResponse/ns:result/ns:records`.

When you do your `xsl:value-of`, you are starting your select with `//` which is starting from the beginning of the document. Try making the select relative to the current context...

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <sfdc:sObjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc" type="OpportunityContactRole">
      <xsl:for-each select="//ns:queryResponse/ns:result/ns:records">
        <xsl:if test="sf:Contacts/ns:done = 'true' and sf:Opportunities/ns:done = 'true'"> 
          <sfdc:sObject>
            <sfdc:ContactId>
              <xsl:value-of select="sf:Contacts/ns:records/sf:Id[1]"/>
            </sfdc:ContactId>
            <sfdc:IsPrimary>True</sfdc:IsPrimary>
            <OpportunityId>
              <xsl:value-of select="sf:Opportunities/ns:records/sf:Id[1]"/>
            </OpportunityId>
            <sfdc:Role>Purchaser</sfdc:Role>
          </sfdc:sObject>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </sfdc:sObjects>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Edit:** You should also make the xpaths in the `xsl:if` relative to the current context. Updated the template above.

You could also move the test to a predicate in the `xsl:for-each` and remove the `xsl:if` entirely...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ns:queryResponse/ns:result/ns:records[sf:Contacts/ns:done = 'true' and sf:Opportunities/ns:done = 'true']">
  <sfdc:sObject>
      ...
  </sfdc:sObject>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your xpath : `//ns:records/sf:Contacts/ns:records/sf:Id[1]/text()` to remove `//ns:records`

So it will be just `sf:Contacts/ns:records/sf:Id[1]/text()`

and

`//ns:records/sf:Opportunities/ns:records/sf:Id[1]/text()` to `sf:Opportunities/ns:records/sf:Id[1]/text()`